# Node.js Sequelize UUID primary key + Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, graphql

I try to create database model by using sequelize but I'm facing a problem with model's primary key.

#### Setting

I'm using Postgres (v10) in docker container and sequalize (Node.js v10.1.0
) for models and GraphQL (0.13.2) + GraphQL-Sequalize (8.1.0) for request processing.

#### Problem

After creating models by sequelize-cli I've **manually tried to replace id column with uuid**. Here's my model migration that I'm using.

```
'use strict';
const DataTypes = require('sequelize').DataTypes;

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Currencies', {
      uuid: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      ticker: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      alt_tickers: {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING)
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Currencies');
  }
};
```

Model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Currency = sequelize.define('Currency', {
        uuid: DataTypes.UUID,
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        ticker: DataTypes.STRING,
        alt_tickers: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING)
    }, {});
    Currency.associate = function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
    };
    return Currency;
};
```

Due to some problem sequalize executes next expression:

> Executing (default): SELECT "id", "uuid", "name", "ticker", "alt_tickers", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Currencies" AS "Currency" ORDER BY "Currency"."id" ASC;

That leads to "column 'id' doesn't exist" error.

Alternatively, I've tried to fix it by renaming *uuid* column to *id* at migration:

```
  ...      
  id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4()
  },
  ...
```

And at the model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Currency = sequelize.define('Currency', {
        id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        ticker: DataTypes.STRING,
        alt_tickers: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING)
    }, {});
    Currency.associate = function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
    };
    return Currency;
};
```

but the result was the following error at the start of the program:

> Error: A column called 'id' was added to the attributes of 'Currencies' but not marked with 'primaryKey: true'

#### Questions

- So, is there a way to force sequelize to use UUID as the tables primary key without defining id column?
- Is there a way to create columns without id columns?
- What possibly caused this errors and how should fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you have not posted here is your `model` code. This is what I think has happened

1. The database has been manually changed from `id` to `uuid`.
2. Your model does not reflect this change.

Hence the query is searching for both `id` and `uuid`.

You can fix this my defining `uuid` in your model like below and making it a primary key

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  uuid: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV1,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
});

sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => User.create({
    username: 'test123'
  }).then((user) => {
    console.log(user);
  }));
```

Comment: Actually, the model has been changed in the first place. I've also tried to rollback to Integer "id", but the primary key was not set in the database.

Comment: Sure. Take a look.

Comment: The model still shows `id` field? it should be `uuid`. You should also make it primary key `primaryKey: true`

Comment: I've provided two cases. First is the table with *uuid* as UUID data type and second with *id* as UUID data type, so two models are provided, one after another. If I understood you correct you want me to add a primary key to migration but that is already done.

Comment: Model and DB declaration of primary key should happen independently and recommended. So if you are solving `Error: A column called 'id' was added to the attributes of 'Currencies', you should make it primary key in the model as well as in the db as the query is generated by the Sequelize

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15):

This is just about the only resource I've found online that explains what it takes to set up a UUID column that the *database* provides defaults for, without relying on the third-party `uuid` npm package: https://krmannix.com/2017/05/23/postgres-autogenerated-uuids-with-sequelize/

Short version:

1. You'll need to install the "uuid-ossp" postgres extension, using a sqlz migration
2. When defining the table, use this `defaultValue`: `Sequelize.literal( 'uuid_generate_v4()' )`